# Is it possible to launch a process by double click a jar file on windows?

Tags: java, jar

I wrote this tiny java program to learn how jar file works on Windows.

```
package ch01;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(sc.next());
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
}
```

I made a build using the following

```
javac ch01/Hello.java
java ch01.Hello
jar cfe ch01.jar ch01.Hello ch01/*.class
```

and this command

```
java -jar ch01.jar
```

managed to invoke the program from windows cmd, and the process showed up in Task Manager

However, when I double click the jar file from file explorer, nothing happened, no console was launched, no process was running. What am I missing?

Comment: There is no console if you launch it by double-clicking. Therefore, reading from `System.in` doesn't work.

Comment: @dan1st – Of course reading from `System.in` will work! Although not in the intended way/not that straight forward as one would expect! `System.in` will always exist, and you can read from it, but in the worst case it is associated with `/dev/nul` … meaning there is no input data to read.

Comment: With not work, I meant that it will not read anything the user can enter.

Comment: @dan1st – There is nothing where the user can enter something … but that is not the problem of the Java program, it is something you have to solve on the Windows level. The Java program will read the input stream, but Windows do not provide you/the user any means to write to that input stream. Be more precise with your error descriptions …

Comment: It is the reason why it doesn't appear in the task manager - it completes instantly because `sc.next()` won't block.

Comment: @dan1st – No, the `scan.next()` will block indefinitely! The program did not even start because there is no manifest with the `Main-Class` entry. Therefore the JVM does not know which class it should execute.

Comment: He said that `java -jar ch01.jar` worked so the manifest is ok. And yes, System.in may block indefibetely but it could also complete instantly if it is reading from `nul`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a manifest file that is added to the jar file, with the `-m` or `--manifest` option:

```
jar --manifest=manifest.mf …
```

That manifest file must contain an entry like below:

```
Main-Class: ch01.Hello
```

Also see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

And of course you need to configure your Windows in a way that `*.jar` files are linked to `java.exe`.